# django rest framework accessing and editing nested model

Tags: django, rest, api, django-rest-framework

Let's say I've got 2 models

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Language(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(
        Person, related_name='prs', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

I want to be able to access all persons languages like that -> `person/{person_id}/language`
and to access and edit specific language like that -> `person/{person_id}/language/{language_id}`

Comment: You will have to write custom serializer.

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, you can use [drf-nested-routers](https://github.com/alanjds/drf-nested-routers) package.

As you are new to DRF, I know there is chance that you haven't seen `routers` and `ModelViewSet` yet, so I would recommend you to go through that first. [Here](https://medium.com/@MicroPyramid/understanding-routers-in-django-rest-framework-4005718895bd) is the link which explains this flow.

Comment: thank You :) i've heard about it but wasn't sure if it's a right way to go since what i'm doing is a 'homework' for a junior dev interview and i didn't expect to be forced to use some external libraries.